# Codec supported by most exernal DVD/Video players

Tags: video, conversion, codec

My video camera records video using H.264 codec, although it does not look like old DVD players support this format.

I would like to convert these videos into some most commonly found, generic format, which is most likely to be supported by most of the DVD players out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many DVD players have the *DivX* logo on their front:

[image]

This means that you will be fine using a [MPEG-4 Part 2 codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_2). MPEG-4 Part 2 videos can be found in AVI files. AVI containers are really old and considered legacy, but this is the only reason they will play on most devices.

Thus, if you use any of these encoders, creating an AVI file, you should be fine.

- [3ivx](http://www.3ivx.com/)
- [DivX](http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus/converter) (but this might cost you)
- [XviD](http://www.xvid.org/)
- [libavcodec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec)

As `libavcodec` is free and open source, it is implemented in many applications. You can therefore use the following software for creating MPEG-4 AVI videos:

- [SUPER©](http://www.erightsoft.com/S6Kg1.html) (download link at the bottom)
- [Format Factory](http://pcfreetime.com/) (looks weird, but it's okay)
- [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) (has unfortunately dropped AVI support, so your mileage may vary)

Again, I'd like to stress that libavcodec is free. Therefore, **don't pay for software** to encode videos unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either WMV or an older an older DivX codec. Something in the 4.x range, perhaps. I can remember DVD players from as far back as 10 years ago that support these formats.